# Script Editor in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a page with `Script Editor`. now I need to add another one to try something without running the code at the first `Script Editor`.

Is there a method to disable the first `Script Editor` on my page without delete it or comment the code within it ?

Comment: The answer is No. It is like asking: I have two lines in my code, how can I run line 2 and not run line 1. Now SP does make it possible to exclude a line with Target Audience setting in the webpart properties.. but that requires different logins. Alternative you could change line 1 (script 1) to not run when there is a QueryParameter

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a document "script" Element after some logic?

```
var myscript = document.createElement('script');    
myscript.setAttribute('src','http://yoursite/myscript.js');    
document.head.appendChild(myscript);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but Should you tell me what this will do ?

Comment: That code creates a DOM script element in runtime.  I've used it in some script editor (and content editor) to select which code to add programmatically.
check more at: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_script.asp

Comment: I really appreciated your answer , but what I need is to disable script at first script editor web part to run a second script  at another script editor at the same page that is not related to the first one , so please tell me how I can use the above code to achieve this scenario , thanks in advance

Comment: ok, I'll take the time later to try to give you an example.